# Create multiple recipient by using jtextfield

Tags: java, jtextfield, jcombobox, jlist

Hello i want to create an email where user can send to multiple recipient This email i have already stored it in my database. When starting the program i call it from db and fill inside a `jcombobox`. Now i want when a user choose from the `jcombobox` it will place it in the `jtextfield`. I only manage to get only one email at a time. I want when user select multiple email it will put to the `jTextfield`

I want the result like this in my TextField :
`abc@yahoo.com , rfr@gmail.com , rrr@yahoo.com`

My code below only can get one value a time:

```
String value1 =    jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
multiple.setModel(value1.)
```

I tried to check on jlist but dont know how to use the getmodel. Dont know whether it is a good idea or not..Kindly help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JComboBox does not support multiple selections. But, you could always generate the mail recipient string by appending each selection done in the JComboBox, using an ActionListener or the like?

```
String emails = "";

jComboBox2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void performAction(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Get selected item...
        String value1 = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (emails.length() > 0)
            emails += " , ";

        emails += value1;
    }
});

multiple.setModel(value1);
```